# Is it possible to use wasm-bindgen with webpack 5?

Tags: webpack, rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, wasm-pack

I followed the [Hello World](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/examples/hello-world.html) **Guide** for [wasm-bindgen](https://crates.io/crates/wasm-bindgen) (I am using `wasm-bindgen = "0.2.72"`).

Unfortunately the npm packages mentioned in the guide are not really up to date. Because I would like to have a clean starting point, I tried to upgrade them.

This is the `package.json` mentioned in the guide:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wasm-tool/wasm-pack-plugin": "1.0.1",
    "text-encoding": "^0.7.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

I removed `text-encoding` (because I do not care about not supporting the non Chromium based version of *Edge*) and upgraded `@wasm-tool/wasm-pack-plugin` without Issues:

Working `package.json`:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wasm-tool/wasm-pack-plugin": "^1.3.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Working `webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const WasmPackPlugin = require("@wasm-tool/wasm-pack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'index.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'index.html'
        }),
        new WasmPackPlugin({
            crateDirectory: path.resolve(__dirname, ".")
        })
    ],
    mode: 'development'
};
```

The next thing I did was upgrading the `html-webpack-plugin` and `webpack` itself.

The `package.json` of the version with the error:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wasm-tool/wasm-pack-plugin": "^1.3.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.27.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Because I upgraded `webpack` to version `5.27.1` I also had to change the `webpack.config.js` like this:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const WasmPackPlugin = require("@wasm-tool/wasm-pack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'index.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'index.html'
        }),
        new WasmPackPlugin({
            crateDirectory: path.resolve(__dirname, ".")
        })
    ],
    experiments: {
        asyncWebAssembly: true
    },
    mode: 'development'
};
```

Now when I run `npm run serve` the build completes without errors, but when I open the webpage no alert is shown anymore. In the browser console the following error is now logged:

```
TypeError: _index_bg_wasm__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is undefined
    greet webpack:///./pkg/index_bg.js?:113
    <anonymous> webpack:///./index.js?:4
    promise callback* webpack:///./index.js?:4
    js http://localhost:8080/index.js:18
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:8080/index.js:366
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8080/index.js:709
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8080/index.js:712
```

What do I have to do, to get rid of this Issue, so that I can use `wasm-bindgen` with `webpack ^5.27.1`?

I am thankful for any hints whatsoever.

### Additional Observation

Interestingly I found, that even with the not working version, it is possible to remove `m => m.greet('World!')` from `index.js` and instead call the wasm function from `pkg/index.js` like this

```js
import * as wasm from "./index_bg.wasm";
export * from "./index_bg.js";

wasm.greet("World");
```

When I do this, I get no more errors in the console and an alert showing "Hello, !" (missing the "World") is shown, so I think the .wasm should still be fine...

### Update

I was able to get everything working again by using:

```json
experiments: {
    syncWebAssembly: true
},
```

however this is deprecated, so it would be great if there was a way to still use `asyncWebAssembly`.

Comment: Interesting, I think I ran into this before, so this would be a nice opportunity to find out what's causing it. I've created [an issue](https://github.com/wasm-tool/wasm-pack-plugin/issues/104) in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working by loading my application in the following way.

My webpack entry config looks like this:

```
    entry: {
      wasm: ['./src/bootstrap.js'],
      vendor: ['react', 'react-dom'],
    },
```

The bootstrap file looks like this:

```
import('./index.tsx').catch(e =>
  console.error('Error importing `index.getStringX`:', e),
);
```

Further down in my React application I load the wasm package installed with npm like so:

```
import * as wasm from 'myRustWebAssemblyPackedPackage';
```

That's all I do. I don't use any plugins in Webpack.

Comment: The problem is, this won't recompile my Rust wasm package, when I apply changes to my rust code. This is the main reason I use Webpack with the wasm-pack plugin, because it provides the live-reload capability.

Comment: @frankenapps I know this may not be ideal but if you use my approach and then install `cargo-watch` and run `cargo watch -i .gitignore -i "pkg/*" -s "wasm-pack build"` in tandem with your webpack watch, then cargo will call the `wasm-pack build` command updating the `pkg` directory which webpack is watching on and rebuild.

Comment: I am accepting this as a workaround for now. Hopefully this will be resolved in the `wasm-pack` plugin.

Comment: had to add "console.log('wasm='+wasm);" after ipmort, otherwise webpack was repoting '(webassembly) [orphan] and thing wasn't loaded

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is officially supported now, as [committed](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/blob/eba691f38ca427c9d440b3d4c44217e58c89c661/examples/hello_world/package.json#L10) in Aug 10, 2021 to the main branch. Note, that as of Dec 2022, if you are cloning from wasm-bindgen GitHub, you need to copy examples out of wasm-bindgen root, [see related issue](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/1394). Don't forget to `npm i` before proceeding with `npm run serve`