# Reading parquet format from javascript application bundled with webpack 5

Tags: javascript, webpack, parquet, webassembly, duckdb

I am developping a web application, in javascript, with webpack 5 bundler. I am looking for *any* solution so that my application can use parquet data (download on-the-fly and decode).

So far, I tried the following javascript libraries:

- ParquetJS - https://github.com/ironSource/parquetjs#usage-reading-files
- ParquetJS-lite - https://github.com/ZJONSSON/parquetjs#reading-data-from-a-url
- Parquet-wasm - https://github.com/kylebarron/parquet-wasm
- DuckDB https://www.npmjs.com/package/duckdb
- DuckDB-wasm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@duckdb/duckdb-wasm

but the webpack bundling process fails for all of them (for various reasons). I am using webpack 5.

Is there an up-to-date solution to decode parquet data in a webpack-5-bundled javascript application ?

Comment: you could try duckdb (it can read parquet file from http endpoint https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/import/http_import) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74205773/6563567

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Kind of ! See https://github.com/eurostat/gridviz-parquet
I am not fully satistied but that's working...

Comment: Does this help you for parquet-wasm? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66755283